# Choosing topological rule to have polygons from one feature class be filled, in their entirety, with polygons from multiple feature classes

Tags: arcgis-pro, topology

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I am trying to get polygons from a class to be filled entirely with polygons from multiple other classes. The 'Must Be Covered By Feature Class Of' rule would seem to do fine, except for the fact that this pertains to the original class being covered by a SINGLE other class, when I need coverage from multiple classes. For example, a California polygon being covered in its entirety by multiple terrain type polygons, such as mountains, desert, chaparral, etc. Also, this set of topology entirely corresponds to polygons only (Area and Area-Area rules).

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting up a separate rule for each polygon feature class you need the original feature class to be covered by. You should be able to implement the same rule multiple times.